# Match sound files to imageview or image click

Tags: java, android, image, audio, android-imageview

I'm new to android development and i was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the matching sound files depending on an image click. I have 6 images that are in random order so i want to play the appropriate sound depending on what image i clicked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a [tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atag) for a view, both in xml and Java, containing "additional information". In this case you may want to set the related audio resource / file name.

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned by @LeartS, you could set the `tag` property of the image:

```
img1.setTag("\path\to\audio.mp3");
```

or

```
android:tag="@string/some_file"
```

And retrieve it when needed

```
public void onClick(View v){
    play(img1.getTag().toString());
}
```

Another another way that you could do it would by using the IDs of the image views

Create a final ID

```
final int ID_IMG_APPLE = 0x0001;
```

Set the ID to the view

```
img1.setId(ID_IMG_APPLE);
```

Check the ID when a view is clicked:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
    case ID_IMG_APPLE:
        play("apple.mp3");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me a quick example of how it would look for the xml and Java?

Comment: Above are both XML and java examples for both xml and java, try it, and see what you have problems with.

Comment: i'm trying the first one. but i have trouble with OnClick.. What do i replace img1 with?

Comment: you have to get the view from the layout: `findViewById(R.id.my_view).setTag("someString");`